# C# Use Linq to Extract a single XML attribute for each XML file in a directory

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, data-extraction

How do I use Linq to extract a single XML attribute form each XML file in a directory and put that element in a C# list. Do I have to loop thru each file one-by-one? The XML files are quite large so I'd like to do this without loading the entire file into memory.

Thanks,
j

Comment: How big are these files?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the files are massive (100 MB+) I would be unable to turn down the elegance of this code:

```
var result = Directory.GetFiles(filePath)
    .Select(path => XDocument.Load(path))
    .Select(doc => doc.Root.Element("A").Attribute("B").Value)
    .ToList();
```

*I really hope your XML files are not that big though...*

Answer (score 1):

You do have to go through every file, and this will mean at least parsing enough of the XML content of each file to get to the required attribute.

`XDocument` (i.e. LINQ to SQL) will parse and load the complete document in each case, so you might be better using an `XmlReader` instance directly. This will require more work: you will have to read the XML nodes until you get to the right one, keeping track of where you are.